# Ajax request is executed twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, apache, http

The following code snippet written using jQuery and meant for sending data is executed twice on a single click. Both HTTP requests give 200 as response.

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
        $(this).unbind("click");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/publish/",
            data: $("#submit-story").serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#send-draft').html('saving...');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#send-draft').html('Draft');
                //window.location.href = "/home/"
            }

        });

    });
});
```

This is Django template for HTML. This is django template so i skipped the header and footer part as it doesn't contain anything relevant to the my problem.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'workout/wysiwyg-advanced/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" />
```

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#story').editable({});
});
</script>

<div class="header" id="new-story-head"> 
    <div id="logo">W</div><div id="story-writer">  <img src="{% static 'workout/images/business_user.png' %}" align="absmiddle" /> {{ user.username }} 
        <span id="send-draft"> Draft </span> </div>
    <div class="right-top">
        <button id="red">Delete</button>
       <!-- <button id="grey">History</button>-->
        <button id="grey">Send Draft</button>  
        <input type="submit" id="green" value="Publish">       
     </div> 
</div>




<div class="content" id="new-story">
    <div class="center">
        <form class="story"  name="story"   id="submit-story">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="image"><img id="addheader" src="{% static 'workout/images/add-image.png' %}" /></div>

            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" value='{{blog.title}}' /> <br />
            <input type="text" id="sub_title" name="subtitle" placeholder="Subtitle" value='{{blog.subtitle}}'/> <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="blog_id" value="{{ blog_id }}" />
            <textarea name="content" placeholder="Write your Story" rows="50" cols="60" id="story">{{blog.content|safe}}</textarea>

        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: make sure you are creating only 1 event listener for submit. either on submit or click etc. can you show your html as well?

Comment: Well there is no submit button below the form. Does it still gonna submit form ? with default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the onclick event for the submit button

```
<button id="green" value="Publish" onclick="javascript:return callonclick();"></button>
<script>
function callonclick(){
//Do your ajax call here
return false;
}

</script>
```

Comment: This is not working. Its again giving two request as in my case

Comment: @HarshitChaudhary jus use '$.ajax({type: "POST",url: "/publish/",data: $("#submit-story").serialize(),success:function(data) {  }});' in onclick function and get rid of rest of the crap

Comment: But While request is processing, I need an indicator to assure user whats going on if it is saving... or saved i.e. draft
apart from it removing this extra piece of code doesn't had any effect